# php using variable type checking functions to check if null

Tags: php

Can I use functions like `is_integer()`, `is_string()`, and other like them as a reliable check to see if the variable is null? I guess what I am asking is if the variable is null with they all return false?

Comment: Well, if the variable is `null` you can conclude that `is_string()` gives you `false`. But if `is_string()` gives you `false`, the variable is not necessary `null`.... so **no**, you cannot use to check them whether a variable is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use type comparison.

```
$somevar === null
```

Comment: Same as with `is_null()`: Requires the existence of the variable (`isset()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either is_null() or use type comparison (===). They're virtually the same, except that type comparison will be *slightly* faster (by slightly I mean so abysmal that it almost doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

All of the `is_*()` functions tests the type of a value, thats theire main purpose. To test, if a variable is `null`, just test it ;)

```
is_null($var)
```

Comment: and keep in mind that is_null() means that it already passed isset()

Comment: You're right, but as far as I know thats required in any case.